# Expectation of Wordle score

Tags: survival, expected-value, censoring

I am interested in determining the expectation for a person's wordle score.  If the person guessed the word every time, this would be straight-forward using simple expected value calculations.  However, how would one handle the the fact that sometimes, you need more than $6$ guesses?  At the outset, the data we're working with is not completely quantitative since the outcomes are that you can guess the word in $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, or $6$ guesses, or you can get $X/6$ meaning you did not correctly guess the word. I am most interested in any statistical theory that deals with this or similar situations.

Let $X$ be the random variable (not sure if r.v. is even the proper notion here) that describes the guess distribution.

My personal wordle stats are:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18 | 126 | 182 | 122 | 37 | 5 |

Of course, we can describe the expectation of our guess given that the guess is 6 or fewer, and this gives an expectation of
$$4.07 = 1 \cdot 0 + 2 \cdot 18/485 + 3 \cdot 126/485+4 \cdot 182/485+ 5 \cdot 122/485+6\cdot 37/485$$

On the other hand, I could use "guess" that every time I miss the Wordle word, I would get it if I had 2 or 3 more tries.  This means that I could guess I had the actual distribution of

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18 | 126 | 182 | 122 | 37 | 5 |

This gives an expected value of

$$4.12 = 1 \cdot 0 + 2 \cdot 18/490 + 3 \cdot 126/490+4 \cdot 182/490+ 5 \cdot 122/490+6\cdot 37/490$$

which is quite close.  What is the "proper" way to handle this?

Comment: Welcome to CV, David. Since few people play Wordle by *purely* guessing, and (more subtly) how an intelligent, rational player guesses depends on what they know about *two* different dictionaries (namely, the dictionary of possible targets and a larger dictionary of possible guesses), there is no well-defined expected value until you specify the method of play and both dictionaries.  By "handle this," then, are you asking how to obtain a realistic expectation or are you focused on the fact that the number of guesses is *right censored*?

Comment: By "handle this" I mean how do you fix the fact that data is missing/qualitative?  Is there a reasonable way to define an expected value in such a case?  In the case I gave above, the expectation was more or less the same regardless of how we handle the "misses," but I doubt that is true in general.

Comment: As I wrote, these are right-censored data.  Provided you have a suitable model for the guesses (which I question, but so what), methods of *survival analysis* and *censored regression* would be worth looking into.  These are *not* missing data: when you reach the limit of six guesses, that's still data.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the similar results for `Absurdle`, which is like `Wordle`, but the computer cheats.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  The term I was looking for was "right-censoring" which I had misread/misinterpreted in your original comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple parametric approach which works by treating the failures as right-censored data. It gives an answer of $4.1065$.

We are going to begin by assuming that $X$, the number of incorrect guesses needed before winning Wordle is a [Poisson random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with mean $\lambda$ (*Note: I am not suggesting that this is an appropriate assumption, but it's a good place to start.*)

Note that by using the number of incorrect guesses, rather than total guesses, we have shifted the $X$ values so that $0$ is the first possible option.

| X | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $n(X)$ | 0 | 18 | 126 | 182 | 122 | 37 | 5 |

We can write the likelihood function as

$$\begin{align}
L(\lambda | n(0), n(1), \ldots, n(6+)) &= \left(\prod_{i=0}^5P(X = i)^{n(i)}\right)P(X \geq 6)^{n(6+)} \\
&\propto \left(\prod_{i=0}^5(\lambda^ie^{-\lambda})^{n(i)}\right)\left(1 - \sum_{i=0}^5\frac{\lambda^ie^{-\lambda}}{i!}\right)^{n(6+)}
\end{align}$$
and the log-likelihood function becomes

$$\ell(\lambda | n(0), \ldots, n(6+)) = c + \left[\sum_{i=0}^5in(i)\right]\log(\lambda) - \left[\sum_{i=0}^5n(i)\right]\lambda + n(6+) \log\left(1 - \sum_{i=0}^5\frac{\lambda^ie^{-\lambda}}{i!}\right).$$

Now we simply need to find the value of $\lambda$ which maximizes this equation. Without the final term (the right-censored data, part) this would be an easy optimization problem with a closed form answer. The censored data makes this a bit trickier however, and we will need to maximize the likelihood numerically. Here is a simple R script which will accomplish this:

```
# Negative log-likelihood
neg_log_likelihood <- function(lambda, nx, nrc){
  len <- length(nx) - 1
  c1 <- sum((0:len)*nx)
  c2 <- sum(nx)
  prc <- 1 - sum(dpois(0:len, lambda))
  ll <- c1*log(lambda) - c2*lambda + nrc*log(prc)
  return(-ll)
}

# Data
nx <- c(0, 18, 126, 182, 122, 37)
nrc <- 5

# Initial guess for lambda
lam0 <- sum((0:len)*nx/sum(nx))

# Maximize likelihood
lambda_hat <- optim(lam0, neg_log_likelihood, nx=nx, nrc=nrc,
                    method='Brent', lower=0, upper=20)$par
# Print result
lambda_hat
[1] 3.106467
```

If we convert back to the total number of guesses, then we get a reasonable answer of $4.1065$.

This approach can be closely followed, substituting in another distribution in place of the Poisson. Otherwise, I recommend searching this site and others for more information on treating right-censored data.

#### Illustration of Approach (and its Limitations)

If the Poisson assumption is perfectly correct (which it surely isn't), then this method will give a good estimate of the expected number of guesses most of the time. For example, let's look at two cases where the true expected value is $3.5$ ($\lambda = 2.5$).

**Case 1:** $X$ is a Poisson RV

```
NSIMS <- 1e4
lambda_hat <- rep(NA, NSIMS)
for(i in 1:NSIMS){
  x <- rpois(1000, 2.5)
  tx <- table(x)
  nx <- tx[1:5]
  nrc <- sum(tx[-(1:5)])
  lambda_hat[i] <- optim(lam0, neg_log_likelihood, nx=nx, nrc=nrc,
                      method='Brent', lower=0, upper=20)$par
}
hist(lambda_hat)
```

[image]

Note that the sampling distribution for our guess is centered precisely around the true value of $\lambda = 2.5$.

**Case Two:** $X$ is not Poisson (but still has mean $2.5$).

```
lambda_hat <- rep(NA, NSIMS)
for(i in 1:NSIMS){
  x <- rbinom(1000, 10, .75)*rbinom(1000, 1, 1/3)
  tx <- table(x)
  nx <- tx[1:5]
  nrc <- sum(tx[-(1:5)])
  lambda_hat[i] <- optim(lam0, neg_log_likelihood, nx=nx, nrc=nrc,
                         method='Brent', lower=0, upper=20)$par
}
hist(lambda_hat)
```

I chose a particularly bad "true distribution" here, but notice how bad the procedure is at guessing the true value of $\lambda$ when the Poisson assumption is violated. In reality, the data that you shared fits somewhere in between these two cases (although it is almost certainly closer to Case 1).

[image]

Comment: That was very helpful.  Extra thanks for the R code!